# Safari Push Notifications - Verifying hashes in manifest.json failed even though correct

Tags: safari, apple-push-notifications

I have created a push package with the appropriate files as per the Apple spec for APNS. This manifest file represents all of the files that are present:

```
{
    "icon.iconset/icon_128x128.png": "78609fcff69688f969a38f957ac2f10fc79d6732",
    "icon.iconset/icon_128x128@2x.png": "78609fcff69688f969a38f957ac2f10fc79d6732",
    "icon.iconset/icon_16x16.png": "d348589e2cf37d8f23940f8545afe75a2e98b4ac",
    "icon.iconset/icon_16x16@2x.png": "d348589e2cf37d8f23940f8545afe75a2e98b4ac",
    "icon.iconset/icon_32x32.png": "e4418a1c5f2ecfbb702961515aaa65d5449b1c53",
    "icon.iconset/icon_32x32@2x.png": "e4418a1c5f2ecfbb702961515aaa65d5449b1c53",
    "website.json": "45be9c4a6f1bf96e27a9eecab219304b35c5ac24"
}
```

I have manually checked the sha1 values on the CLI and they are all correct, along with the file locations. And yet I still get this error back from Safari each time I try to get permission:

```
{ '{"logs":': { '"Verifying hashes in manifest.json failed"]': '' } }
```

Which is not valid JSON either. Any ideas why this would be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently implemented push notifications through pushwoosh. They automatically created the package for me and I checked how they done it. The only difference between mine manifest file and your is a back slash before the normal slash. Maybe it could do the difference for you. Copy and paste this code in your manifest (I have already added your SHA1 values):

```
{"icon.iconset\/icon_16x16.png":"d348589e2cf37d8f23940f8545afe75a2e98b4ac","icon.iconset\/icon_16x16@2x.png":"d348589e2cf37d8f23940f8545afe75a2e98b4ac","icon.iconset\/icon_32x32.png":"e4418a1c5f2ecfbb702961515aaa65d5449b1c53","icon.iconset\/icon_32x32@2x.png":"e4418a1c5f2ecfbb702961515aaa65d5449b1c53","icon.iconset\/icon_128x128.png":"78609fcff69688f969a38f957ac2f10fc79d6732","icon.iconset\/icon_128x128@2x.png":"78609fcff69688f969a38f957ac2f10fc79d6732","website.json":"45be9c4a6f1bf96e27a9eecab219304b35c5ac24"}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I started out with that format you are showing, and tried without and getting the same result. It would be great if Apple provided some type of pushPackage validator that gave a bit more detail than Safari is posting back to the log resource.

Comment: They have a php file with the code to create the push package but I think you've already seen it, did you?

Answer (score 0):

I created a small ruby script for generating these manifests based on the code in https://github.com/SymmetricInfinity/push_package/blob/master/lib/push_package.rb.

Copy the script into a directory containing an `icon.iconset` directory and your `website.json`. Then you can run `ruby gen_manifest.rb` inside that directory and the script will write the manifest.json. At the very least it may be a sanity check to see that everything is correct. The script is here: https://gist.github.com/adamvduke/7934457

If you don't have any ruby experience, comment back and I can walk you through it.